# JavaScript array on multiple lines

Tags: javascript

I made an array with several strings as values so it becomes one really long line that takes a while to scroll through. To put it on multiple lines I searched and found that I can use a + sign to link the lines, but I'm having a problem. Here's a small example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x;
var colorArr=["Red","Orange","Yellow",+
"Green","Blue","Purple"];
for(x=0;x<6;x++)
document.write(colorArr[x]+"<br/>");
</script>
```

This outputs:

```
Red
Orange
Yellow
NaN
Blue
Purple
```

Basically whichever element is the first on the line becomes undefined for some reason. How do I do this the correct way?

Answer (score 17):

You don't need the `+`, just flow to the next line.  Javascript doesn't equate the end of the line with the end of the statement.

```
var colorArr=["Red","Orange","Yellow",
    "Green","Blue","Purple"];
```

---

To understand the behavior you're seeing, note that this:

```
var test = -"test";
alert(test);
```

Outputs the `NaN` (not a number) that you're seeing.  The parser is attempting to convert "Green" to a number -- so that it can evaluate what it assumes is a math expression (since it begins with `+`).

Comment: Wow I'm dumb for not trying that. I was thinking it worked similar to putting the backslash to separate lines in document.write and stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @user1804208 instead say thank, you should upvote and accept the answer if it helps you.you have asked 16 question .even any single anwer haven't accept

Answer (score 7):

`+ "Green"` is  **not** a number.

Hence the `NaN`

Try just doing this:

```
var colorArr=["Red","Orange","Yellow",
              "Green","Blue","Purple"];
```

---

#### Sidebar:

`NaN` does **not** mean undefined:

```
NaN === undefined; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just press enter and go to the next line, no need for anything syntactically.

The reason it comes up as `NaN` is that it is trying to add a `number` with a `string`.

If you had: `arr = ['whatever', 5 + 10];` it would output `['whatever', 15]`